# Unable to find Element by XPath when Link has Javascript

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to retrieve a hyperlink element in Selenium in which the link is actually executing javascript.  I am unable to retrieve it despite trying several different methods.
< < NOTE: I am able to retrieve other controls - just struggling with this one > > The element looks like the following; trying to retrieve the test1_decode one:

```
<section id="specialsection" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">
<ul class="col4">
    <li  class="header2"><a href="javascript:SetApplication('test1_decode');">Example Application</a></li>
    <li  class="header2"><a href="javascript:SetApplication('test2_decode');">Example Application POC</a></li>
</ul>
</section>
```

I've tried the following: FindElement using XPath contains link text, FindElement using Xpath contains  text, FindElement by PartialLinkText, FindElement by LinkText - all fail.

I even tried getting all < a > in a list; I wonder if maybe it's because it has a 0 height?

```
//These are the different things I've tried:
IWebElement ExAppLogin = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(), 'Example Application')]"));

IWebElement ExAppLogin = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href, 'test1_decode')]"));

IWebElement ExAppLogin = driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("test1_decode"));

IWebElement ExAppLogin = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("test1_decode"));

IWebElement ExAppLogin = driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("test1_decode"));
```

They all generate an exception "Unable to find Element with xpath =="...

Comment: Selenium does seem to have [issues with zero height elements](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6256). Have you tried removing the height restrictions temporarily to see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: When you say remove the height restrictions: do you mean there is a way to Find/parse by ignoring height?  Or do you mean: modify the original page to force it to have a height on the control?  I can't do the latter unfortunately...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Were you able to find the elements in the browser dev tools elements tab with the locator strategies mentioned above?

Comment: And check if you have any iframe, which is wrapping this section.

Comment: @supputuri I was not able to; I am new to Selenium, so assume I know nothing.  How can I do this?

Comment: Which language you are using (Java, C#, Python, Ruby)?

Comment: C#; also: no IFrame present

Comment: `driver.WindowHandles; ` will give you the information if there are any new windows. Just check the count.

Comment: How did you confirmed that there are no ifrmaes? Did you used `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("iframe"))` and the got the length?

Comment: Disregard my latest [ deleted ] comment; I might be close to resolving this - I'll post update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible Solution**
So there *was/were* Iframes - thanks to everyone who commented/responded.
looking at each of these in debug at a breakpoint:

```
driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("iframe"));
driver.FindElements(By.TagName("iframe"));
driver.WindowHandles;
```

I determined that there were iframes.  Since this is a POC, I just hard-coded to retrieve the iframe I wanted:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(2);
```

And I was able progress beyond this point.  What is odd is that even though I was able to find the element I wanted:

```
IWebElement ExAppLogin = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href, 'test1_decode')]"));
```

(i.e. I can view the ExAppLogin variable details in debug since it is not NULL/no exception)
But if I do this:

```
ExAppLogin.Click();
```

nothing happens!

So for the time being I'm able to continue by just executing the javascript:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("SetApplication('test1_decode');");
```

Once I do this, I am encountering *another* issue, but for the purposes of this specific question, I guess I can consider this resolved - thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the following CSS

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='test1_decode']"));
```

The `*=` will match the string inside the href attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, I still get an exception: Unable to find element with css selector == a[href*='test1_decode']

Answer (score 0):

Try following XPath.If this not work please check if there any `iframe` available. And If, then you have to Swith_to iframe first to access the element.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Example Application')][contains(@href,'test1_decode')]"))).click();;
```

Comment: There aren't any IFrames; and for some reason it is not finding any of the values I put in XPath.  I *think* it has to do with the fact that it is not visible/height=0?

Comment: @MattR Did you try inducing a WebDriverWait as suggested?

Comment: I did it in java.I don’t know c#. The logic remain same only syntax would be different.

Comment: I did do that; it turns out my issue was related to IFrames. Thank you!

Comment: @MattR : I told you but you denied earlier.